# Paying someone to give me money

Tags: scams

I have someone that wants to bless me with a large amount of money. I am working on a project. But I see some red flags they want to send me cash in a package. They have been trying to send it for 3 weeks.

But they said I had to pay for it when it comes. So much is going on I do not know what to think or feel. It's coming out of Africa. I ask them did I have to pay the money back they said no its a gift. But I am feeling something my family says its a scam I do not know what to do.

I ask them to put the money on my pay pal account but for the amount, they can not do it. I do not know what to do. And I need it for the project I am working on

Comment: Do they want you to pay them back part of it?

Comment: Have you shared any personal information with these people yet?  Name, address, scans of any ID cards or passports?  If so, contact the relevant authorities to get a new one issued and notify them that the old one may be compromised.  If not, **don't do it.**  If *they've* shown *you* any kind of identification to "prove their identity" then be aware that those documents were likely stolen from someone else they scammed.

Answer (score 25):

If someone you don't know wants to give you money for nothing of value in return but expects you to pay for it first, they are trying to pull an [advance fee scam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_scam) on you.

When you realize that someone is trying to scam you, then the wisest course of action is to simply stop responding to them. They will just give up after a while. [Scam baiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scam_baiting) sounds like a fun hobby, but it can become a lot less fun when the scammers start to make credible threats of physical violence.

Comment: Credible threats? Any cases that I might be able to read up on. I was under the impression that their threats amounted to your chance of being bitten by a dog your watching on YouTube.

Comment: @Tolure That might be true in general, but it only takes **one** who actually *can* make credible threats to ruin your whole day.  My understanding is that these "Nigerian prince" scammers are often connected to organized crime in their home country.  *Most of them* might be low ranking minions who can't really do anything to you, but if you happen to piss off the one in a thousand who's actually climbing the ladder...

Answer (score 8):

Let's ignore the fact that there is nobody in Africa who wants to bless you with a large amount of money.

Let's say I have £800,000 in my UK bank account, and I want you to have a million dollars.

I can tell my bank "Please put a million dollars into Mascheria's bank account". They will do that and charge me one million converted to pound, plus all fees.

Or I can tell my bank "Here's £800,000, please put as much money as you can into Mascheria's bank account". They will do that, it will cost me exactly £800,000, and you will have a million dollar plus or minus a bit in your account.

Or the first scenario, but the bank tells me "there are $100 in fees to pay", so I tell the bank to put $999,900 into your bank account.

In neither case do you have to pay any fees first. So yes, this is a scam. This happens more often with lotteries. Most lotteries pay out the money, and pay all the fees. Some lotteries pay out the money minus fees. No genuine lottery *ever* asks you to pay to get your winnings. If they ask you to pay, it's a scam.